# Connect remote Desktop from Raspberry to another pc

Tags: rdp

Is it possible to open a rdp from raspberry to another pc ??

Answer (score 2):

I'm reading this as you want to use your RPi as an RDP *client* to connect to a remote Windows computer. If this is the case, try installing the `remmina` package. I've used it as an RDP client to Windows machines, and it works very well.

Answer (score 0):

You can install RDP via the command line (see this [forum thread](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=18832)) [instructions here](http://www.raspberrypiblog.com/2012/10/how-to-setup-remote-desktop-from.html)

**RASPBERRY PI**

1. Start up your Pi to the terminal prompt.
2. Type the following command

   ```
   sudo apt-get install xrdp
   ```
3. If promoted enter your password (the default is "raspberry")
4. Type "Y" and press enter.
5. This is now installing xrdp onto your Pi which is the software we are going to use for the remote desktop connection.  Wait for it to complete.
   Restart your Pi.  We are going to check that xrdp is going to start up automatically.
6. When your Pi has booted to the command prompt look for [ ok ] Starting Remote Desktop Protocol server : xrdp sesman.  This shows you that xrdp is installed and automatically starting up on start up of your Pi
7. The last step is to make a note of the IP address of your Pi which should also be displayed on the start up screen.  Run the command

   ```
   hostname -I
   ```

to find out your I.P. This is the address of your Pi on your network and what we will use to connect to your Pi from the second machine.

**ON THE REMOTE COMPUTER**

1. Launch Remote Desktop Connection which can be found at Start->All Programs->Accessories->Remote Desktop Connection
2. Type in the IP Address for your Pi which you noted above.
3. Click Connect (you may get a security warning at this stage just click OK if you do.  After all it is your Pi on your network so nothing to worry about security wise).
4. Leave the Module on the default of sesman-Xvnc and enter your username and password for your Pi.  (The default is pi and raspberry if you haven't changed them).
5. Click OK and after a few moments you should be greeted my your Raspberry Pi's desktop!

---

I would rather recommend you use the built in VNC:

You need to do some [setup](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/vnc/) though

1. Download [VNC Viewer](https://www.realvnc.com/en/connect/download/viewer/) to the computer you want to use to connect

On the Raspberry Pi

**On the desktop GUI**:

1. On your Raspberry Pi, boot into the graphical desktop.
2. Select Menu > Preferences > Raspberry Pi Configuration > Interfaces.
3. Ensure VNC is Enabled.

**In the command line**

1. sudo raspi-config
2. navigate to Interfacing Options.
3. scroll down and select VNC > Yes.

**Alternatively on the command line** (wrote this puppy myself)

```
 sudo systemctl enable vncserver-x11-serviced.service && systemctl start vncserver-x11-serviced.service && echo "VNC started: $(hostname -I)"
```